# Partitioning of a Self Organizing Map (SOM) in n clusters

Tags: clustering, self-organizing-maps

I created the following 9x9 SOM (yellow = small distance between two neurons, red/black = large distance):

[image]

I know that I can regard each neuron as a separate cluster and that neurons with small distances can be regarded as bigger clusters but I am wondering if there is any (algorithmic) approach to split the whole SOM into n clusters. Looking at my map I would suggest to split the map into 3 clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the question is vague, but the answer is that you must identify a statistical property that can separate the map into m distinct regions within your acceptable margin of error.